# Why 'notify.js is not a function' problem occurs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how I embedded sources and links to my webpage, including notify.js:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-notify.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/notify.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

and this is my JS where I'm using this library:

```
    $("#accountBtn").on("click", function () {
        $.notify("Click me!");
    });
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, no notification pops-up. I got this error on the console: *Uncaught TypeError: $.notify is not a function at HTMLInputElement.*

I used similar chunk of code in:

```
    $('document').ready(function () {...}
```

as well but in vain. Maybe is something wrong with links? Really, have no idea what's wrong

Comment: In your developer tools console, what is output if you type `typeof $.notify`

Comment: use developer tools (hit F12 on chrome) check if notify.js script loads correctly

Comment: you have "jquery-notify.js" in your code - check if that is the real name of that file (by default it is just "notify.js")

Comment: @Bravo the type is "object"

Comment: @webdev-dan I tried notify.js but it is not a proper name for file, proper one is jquery-notify.js. And yes, it loads correctly. However I got this error message back: _TypeError: $.notify is not a function.._

Comment: I installed jQuery.Notify package from NuGet. I added script and content (css) files of this library to Bundles (e.g. I added jquery-notify.js to @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")). Don't know if it's the issue here but don't think so, scipt loads correctly

Comment: so, it's defined ... so why isn't it defined where you use it ... try `jQuery.notify("Click me!");`

Comment: I got this: _jQuery.notify("Click me!");
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.notify is not a function at <anonymous>:1:8_ Really have to idea. I tried on various browsers but in vain

Answer (score -2):

```html
$(document).on("click","#accountBtn", function () {
    //$.notify("Click me!");
    alert(0);
    // If this alert fires, the problem is from your notify, else check that you are properly linking the jquery file
});
```